# Component being notified by a service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular2-observables

I have a service which communicate to a third party service.
The service is executed by several components in the application. I would like to be notified in a generic notification component whenever the service fails ("DoSomethingWhenFails" function).
Currently the generic notification component is referenced in the the  app.component and the service is injected to that component.

I thought of something like eventEmitter which will be emit in the service, but I'm not familiar with this kind of pattern when the service is being injected.
What is the best way of doing it? See my code:

> **app.component.html:**

```
<notify #messageBox ></notify>
```

> **The component:**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent  {

@ViewChild('messageBox') messageBox : notify;

constructor(private someService: SomeService )
```

> **the generic notification component:**

```
export class notification 
{
  ShowNotificationWhenTheServiceFails()
  {
    DoSomethig();
  }
}
```

> **The Service:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class Service{

doSomething(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get<AA>(URL, options).pipe(
     connectToThirdPArtyService();
  }),
   DoSomethingWhenFails();
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use rxjs `Subject` to emit the values whenever an error happens in the service call. you should call the `next()` method.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service{
  public notify$ = new Subject<any>();
  doSomething(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<AA>(URL, options).pipe(
     connectToThirdPArtyService();
  }),
   this.notify$.next(true);
  );
}
```

In your component, you should listen to the notify$ subject as follows using the `subscribe` method, whenever a value gets emitted  using the `next` method, the subscribe method in your component gets called, you can do something inside the `notify$` subscription

```
export class notification implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service:Service) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.notify$.subscribe(messages => {  DoSomethig(); });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the behavior subject to do this.

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('0');
currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

constructor() { }

changeNotification(number) {
this.messageSource.next(number)
}

}
```

parent.component.ts (Notification component in your case)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    {{message}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.changeNotification.subscribe(number => this.number = number)
  }

}
```

When there is a failure you can push to the behavior subject like,

```
constructor(private data: DataService) { }

 onFailure() {
    this.data.changeNotification("1")
  }
```

You can have a number at the service level and increment it onFailure and push it or whatever way wish to.